# Iframes loading error, remote puppeter cdp

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, bots, cloudflare

I have a very strange error.

I sent a code below, I will explain what is happening, I am trying to load a Cloudflare iframe for captcha, it is not possible to use puppeteer stealth because they detect it, it is not possible to customize user-agents, so what did I choose to do , open an instance of chromium and make puppeteer connect to it, but we have a detail, when I make the connections the iframe is no longer detectable, it simply doesn't detect it for some reason, but something curious that I discovered, when I open the Dev Tools seems to work, but remember, in normal puppteer it goes without me opening Dev Tools but it doesn't authenticate because it is considered a Bot, so my question is, why only when I open Dev Tools does it detect the iFrame? Is there an error in the library for this to occur?

NOTE: I tried the flag that automatically opens Dev Tools but Cloudflare detects this too.

```
var chromeLauncher = await import('chrome-launcher');
    var chromePath = chromium.path;
    const chromeFlags = ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-web-security'];

    var chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
        chromePath,
        chromeFlags
    });


    var cdpSession = await CDP({port: chrome.port});

    const {Network, Page, Runtime} = cdpSession;

    await Runtime.enable();
    await Network.enable();
    await Page.enable();
    await Network.setCacheDisabled({ cacheDisabled: true });

    var data = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:' + chrome.port + '/json/version').then(response => {
        response = response.data
        console.log(response.webSocketDebuggerUrl);
        return {
            browserWSEndpoint: response.webSocketDebuggerUrl,
            agent: response['User-Agent']
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err.message)
    })

    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        targetFilter: (target) => !!target.url(),
        browserWSEndpoint: data.browserWSEndpoint,
    });
    const pages = await browser.pages();
    const page = pages[0];
    await page.setUserAgent(data.agent);
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
    });
```

I tried using stealth, I tried using the default puppeter, I tried using other stealths, I tried letting Dev Tools open automatically in the tabs, but Cloudflare detects this.